# error in it is giving error pipeline must be a list i'm creating command_cursor

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x

```
myresults = db.persona.aggregate(([{
    "$match": {
        "id": {
            "$gte": (1)
        },
        "$or": [{
            "id": {
                "$lte": (20000)
            }
        }]
    }
}], {
    'cursor': {
        'batchSize': 0
    }
}), useCursor = False)
```

please help me with this i'm creating command_cursor in python using pymongo 
i'm facing this problem. it is giving error pipeline must be a list

Comment: And also i want to add limit for the fields its not working

Comment: please error also..

Comment: do you have a condition of id >= 1 or id <= 20000 ?

Comment: @rockie-yang did Shaishab's answer solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the green checkmark answer!

Comment: @Diana, thanks for raise it. it was not my question. what I did was some editing of format. The question will have to go the original author.

Answer (score 1):

You missed syntax and possible to update query. can try this

```
db.persona.aggregate(
  [
    {
      "$match": {
        $or: [
          {"id": {"$gte": 1}},
          {"id": {"$lte": 20000}}
        ]
      }

    },
    {$skip: 5},
    {$limit: 10}
  ],
  {'cursor': {'batchSize': 0}}
)
```